Clarification Regarding a Possible Typo in David J. Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics
Question:
I am currently reading Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J. Griffiths, and I’ve encountered a point of confusion in Section 2.4 on page 91.
Why is $W=\int_a^b\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{l}$ equals to $-Q\int_a^b\textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{l}$ since $\textbf{F}=Q \cdot \textbf{E}$. Is there a minus sign missing?
Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J. Griffiths

comparing to The Feynman Lectures on Physics by Richard Feynman:

Here is the answer from David Griffiths (I asked him the same question via email):

Marco, No.  This is simply the definition of work.  The ambiguity (if there is one) is in the meaning of F: If W is the work you must do, then F is the force you must exert, which is -QE.  That's where the minus sign comes in. Sincerely, David Griffiths


A Related Question:
In the same section of the book (also on page 91), I noticed another issue with a missing minus sign:
$$-Q\int_a^b\textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{l} = Q[V(b)-V(a)]$$
Shouldn't the right-hand side also have a minus sign, as indicated by the blue arrow in the image below?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Is there a minus sign missing?

Yes, if you take Griffiths' first definition
$$
\vec F = Q\vec E
$$
and plug that in, there is a minus sign missing. He's using the symbol $\vec F$ to mean two different things in the same paragraph.
He should have written something like:
$$
\vec F_{elec} = Q\vec E
$$
$$
\vec F_{you} = -Q\vec E
$$
$$
W_{you} = \int \vec F_{you}\cdot d\vec\ell
$$
$$
=-Q\int \vec E\cdot d\vec\ell
$$

@htf can you check again I added a related question above :) thx in advance.

Do not edit a previous question to ask more questions. This is a violation of the website's process flow. Just post a NEW question. @MarcoMoldenhauer

Your new question can link to your old question if you want

But, briefly: Please make sure you remember that $\vec E \equiv -\vec\nabla V$, by definition, so there is another negative to keep track of. @MarcoMoldenhauer

$-Q\int_a^b \vec E \cdot d\vec {\ell} = +Q\int_a^b \nabla V\cdot d\vec\ell = +Q(V(b) - V(a))$

So, there is no additional typo/error

Ok thanks a lot htf! Can you explain why it is negative? I did not find this article very helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/412191/344165. so I did not understand the explanation.

It's negative by convention.

@htf ok Tranks a lot what does that mean? It is as it is? Englisch is not my First Language.

I mean that we have all agreed on the sign, so there is no real answer to "why?" It is just a historical choice/definition. For example, in the equation $\vec F = -\nabla U$, where $U$ is the potential energy, there is a negative sign. That is just the way it is. Similarly, in the equation $\vec E = -\nabla V$, there is a negative sign, by definition, because we all agree on the definition as a historical artifact.
